# Reverse string to a certain length

Tags: c++, reverse

I have a string and want to reverse it only up to a certain length. Suppose till length 8 or 6 or something like that. How to do without using loop.

The below code reverse the full string.

```
std::string str = "ADCFFFAA+324424,>>";
reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Comment: The length is determined by the distance between the iterators you passed in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the starting iterator point further into the string without going all the way to the end of the string.

eg:

```
int x = 4;

std::string str = "ADCFFFAA+324424,>>";
reverse(str.begin(), str.begin() + x);
```